# Survey structure for Live Chat Transfer between Agents

Tags: web-app, surveys, chat

I'm developing a live chat application for my site and want to include a post-chat survey to gather feedback on my Agents.

However, I have two types of Agents, for dealing with different queries, and a person engaging in the Chat may be transferred at any time to another Agent from the pool.

I'm concious of the fact that if a person is engaged in the Chat, speaking to Agent A, and then gets transferred to Agent B, that their answers in the Post-Chat Survey may reflect only one or the other, depending on how the Chat Survey is worded.

From doing research, the optimum amount of questions to ask is three. My question to you is, how do I structure the survey to ensure the User answers it with respect to both Agents?

Should I refer to "1st Agent", "2nd Agent", should I double up on the questions, should I include a Survey in between the transfer?

Comment: Any views on this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Andre's answer, I would ensure you are only asking questions about a single agent. Three different strategies:

- Only survey with one agent (Andre)
- If there was more than one agent, randomly select one for whom the survey would apply, and indicate it clearly, e.g.:

  > These questions apply only to Sally, the second agent you interacted with from 1:35 pm to the end of your chat
- Always only survey the last agent, since that experience is freshest in their minds. Once again, indicate clearly to your users.

If you go with the latter two options, it becomes a data science problem. Give your data to your analytics team (which might be you ;-)) and make sure there is a column that indicates the survey "type" - one agent vs. transfer with the selected agent & sequence indicated. Then the results can be appropriately weighted and you can quantify the value of the transfer data vs. the "pure" single agent data via feature selection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the customer would appreciate a survey request in the middle of their live chat. Since the customer is effectively busy, it is likely that they will decline these requests in the majority of cases. I don't think any wording you employ would eliminate the effects you're worried about. Some additional concerns I have about the situation are as follows:

1. Because of [anchoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring), the feedback you get on each agent in a transfer scenario will be biased by the interaction the customer had with the other agent involved in the chat. This means you cannot reliably compare it, or aggregate it with feedback you receive from chats they complete on their own, and/or with other agents.
2. Doubling the questions is counterproductive because you already know that the optimum is 3 questions.
3. If you have 3 questions to work with and you want feedback on both agents, it will be difficult to split the questions equally.
4. Depending on the type of questions to be included in your survey 1(or a max of 2) questions per agent may not return sufficient feedback.

Given the challenges you've mentioned and those above I would consider only providing agent-specific surveys when the customer has interacted with a single agent. The downside of this is that you won't capture any agent feedback on conversations in which transfers take place. However, I would consider capturing chat-specific feedback in these scenarios and find a way to fairly attribute this feedback to both the agents involved in the chat.